# webots can not use 3090 gpu in docker container through X11 forwarding

Tags: webots

I am use X11 forwarding to start webots on a remote server with 3090 GPU, I have installed Nvidia GPU driver on that server, however, when I start webots, it saids the GPU is not meet the requirements because opengl use Mesa/X.org. How to solve this?

```
 > glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa/X.org
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.6, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.2.5
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.2.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 22.2.5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

glxinfo | grep OpenGL should display nvidia card

Comment: It is not clear in your question whether the `glxinfo` is run from the native machine or from the docker. If run from the docker, please explain how do run the docker. Did you follow the instructions provided [here](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/installation-procedure#installing-the-docker-image)?

Comment: @OlivierMichel I have run it in docker and native machine both

Comment: Please correct your question so that it is clear where does the output of your `glxinfo` command come from (docker container or host machine).

Comment: @OlivierMichel docker container, on host it displays nvidia card

Answer (score -1):

You should actually get the NVIDIA driver on both the host machine and inside the docker container.

Here is the procedure to follow:

1. Ensure you have the NVIDIA driver installed on the host machine: `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` should produce something like:

```
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 525.78.01
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 525.78.01
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 525.78.01
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

2. create a docker container with the following `Dockerfile` located in an empty directory:

```
FROM cyberbotics/webots.cloud:R2023a-ubuntu20.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mesa-utils
```

(you may use a different Webots image if needed)

3. Go to this directory and build the docker image: `docker build --tag webots-glxinfo .`
4. Run it: `docker run --tty --rm --gpus=all --env DISPLAY --volume /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw -it webots-glxinfo`
5. Enter the following command:

```bash
# glxinfo | grep OpenGL
```

6. You should get the following output:

```
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 525.78.01
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 525.78.01
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 525.78.01
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

which is basically the very same output as on the host machine.